# Android: keeping overlay textview size same as underlying imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have an image (`.png`) that is sliced into 3 pieces `top`, `middle`, `bottom`. 
(The pieces mentioned are **not** of the same size).

What I am trying to achieve is to have a `layout` where the original image is assembled from the above `3` pieces - but the `middle` piece should also display a `textview` over it.

In a sense, I have managed the most of the above, however with my current `layout` - when the text of the `textview` exceeds some length (horizontally or vertically) the image is then broken, as then there is a gap between middle and bottom part (vertical excess) or the `middle` part is shifted related to the `top` and the `bottom` (horizontal excess).

Actually what I want to achieve is that the `textview` will always remain the same size as the underlying `middle` `imageview`.

My `layout` code is as follows (The code will be used for android `4.0 +`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#88666666"
android:id="@+id/top_layout">
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:paddingTop="25dp" >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivTop"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/quotetops" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivMiddle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/quotemiddles" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ajsdhaj\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhdjajhsdjfhsdjdfjsdjfksdjfkjkfj\ndkfjkdjfkj"        
         />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivBottom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/quotebottoms" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: attach the distortion image screen for reference.

Comment: add image for reference

Comment: Found the solution on my own... thanks, everybody, for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved it by using `android:layout_align...` and referencing the `middle` `imageview`.

(I also, removed the unnecessary `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` from middle `imageview` - but that was not the main problem here)

So, the final layout became:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#88666666"
android:id="@+id/top_layout">
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:paddingTop="25dp" >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivTop"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/quotetops" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivMiddle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/quotemiddles" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ajsdhaj\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhdjajhsdjfhsdjdfjsdjfksdjfkjkfj\ndkfjkdjfkj"    
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivMiddle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivMiddle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivMiddle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivMiddle"     
         />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivBottom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/quotebottoms" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

do this for all three children of `LinearLayout`

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:weight="1dp"
```

for middle element do this for children of `RelativeLayout`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Also you can ditch top `RelativeLayout` as it is redundant. Your final layout file should look like this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:background="#88666666"
    android:id="@+id/top_layout">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/quotetops" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMiddle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:paddingLeft="20dip"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/quotemiddles" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="ajsdhaj\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhdjajhsdjfhsdjdfjsdjfksdjfkjkfj\ndkfjkdjfkj"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/quotebottoms" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Plirkee what sort of distortion you are experiencing ?

Comment: What I have now is the `top` part  has a big gap with the rest of the image ... and some part of the `bottom` image is drawn off-screen (I suppose this is because of the gap and the shifting)....

Comment: You will have to check if image size good as per layout, also if you have given correct padding/margins.

Comment: Before - without the long text inside `textview` - everything looked perfect - now (with your solution) the gap between `top` and the `framelayout` insists - even if I put `android:paddingTop="0dp"` for the frame layout ...

Comment: That is because you had set `ImageView` and `TextView` to `wrap-content`. wrap content will change size with its content. one more thing that you can try here is instead of setting `android:src` on `Imageview` you can set `android:background` but that might cause some stretch in image.

Comment: I thought about background solution - though I would like to avoid the stretching. As far as the first part of your comment goes - that is exactly where my problem relies - I want image view to have `wrap-content` .. and the text view to have the same dimensions that the image view gets (regardless of text view's content) .... but how to achieve that ?

Comment: Changed my answer to suit your needs @Plirkee

Comment: No luck with this either - same problem `top` detached from the `middle` ... `middle` goes somewhat over `bottom` , `bottom` shifts outside the screen...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146508/discussion-between-abhishek-bansal-and-plirkee).

Comment: Found the solution on my own - and posted it here - thank you for your time and effort.